# Have I found a bug in Clang?

Tags: c++, g++, static-members, clang

I tried to compile the code below with `Clang`

```
class Prasoon{

  static const int dummy = 0;

};
int const Prasoon::dummy = 0;

int main(){}
```

The above code did not give any error when compiled with `Clang.`

```
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $ clang++ --version
clang version 2.8 (trunk 107611)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $ cat bug.cpp
class Prasoon{

      private:
      static const int dummy = 0;

    };

int const Prasoon::dummy = 0;

int main(){}
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $ clang++ bug.cpp
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $
```

But when I compiled the same code with `g++` I got an error as expected.

```
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $ g++ bug.cpp
bug.cpp:8: error: duplicate initialization of ‘Prasoon::dummy’
```

So have I found a bug in `Clang`?

Comment: Which clang version are you using? 1.5 on Mac gives the same output as g++ 4.2.1.

Comment: That's in his sample output: clang version 2.8 (trunk 107611)

Comment: Well, it wasn't before the edit ;-)

Comment: You can file the bug here: http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=clang

Comment: @Prasoon saurav: How can I download clang for windows 7? I visited clang' official site but it looks so confusing for me. Please help me & if possible provide a proper link from where I would also be able to download & use clang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you have found a bug.

The rule is expressed in the standard:

> 9.4.2-3:
>   If a static data member is of const
>   literal type, its declaration in the
>   class definition can specify a
>   brace-or- equal-initializer in which
>   every initializer-clause that is an
>   assignment-expression is a constant
>   expression. A static data member of
>   literal type can be declared in the
>   class definition with the constexpr
>   specifier; if so, its declaration
>   shall specify a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer in which
>   every initializer-clause that is an
>   assignment-expression is a constant
>   expression. [ Note: In both these
>   cases, the member may appear in
>   constant expressions. — end note ] **The
>   member shall still be defined in a
>   namespace scope if it is used in the
>   program and the namespace scope
>   definition shall not contain an
>   initializer.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is indeed a bug. I stumbled upon your [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7954) to clang -- thanks for taking the time to submit it :)  While this bug was initially logged as a [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=6904) on 4/23/10, your submission brought it to my attention and I have submitted a simple [patch](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2010-August/010514.html) to the developer's group for their review.