# Assigning a compound literal to a struct with const fields

Tags: c, c99, compound-literals

I have the following code:

**test.c**

```
struct test {
    int const i;
};

void init_test(struct test *t)
{
    *t = (struct test){42};
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc; (void)argv;

    struct test t;
    init_test(&t);
    /* I would expect t={42} here */
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall test.c -o test` fails with the following error:

```
error: assignment of read-only location '*t"
    *t = (struct test){42}
     ^
```

Whereas compiling with `clang -std=c99 -Wall test.c -o test` succeeds and the resulting executable behaves as expected. First of all, is my example code well-formed? Since the function `init_test` takes a pointer to a non-const `struct test` I am unsure why GCC thinks I am attempting to modify a read-only variable. It seems to me that I am just bitwise assigning a literal of type `struct test` to the (stack) variable `t`, and it seems irrelevant that a field of the struct is marked `const`. GCC will compile fine when `const` is removed. What is going on here?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531296/have-i-found-a-bug-in-clang

Comment: `void foo(struct bar { const int n; } b1, struct bar b2) { b1 = b2; }` also reproduces the issue (clang gives a warning for the structure definition being visible only in this function, which is good but unrelated here).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527984/which-c99-compiler-clang-vs-gcc-is-closer-to-standard-on-const-structure-fiel -- looks like a bug (but I couldn't find a bug report). Can you give your clang version? And maybe download the newest version and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not something specific to compound literals. A structure `const` member can only be initialized, it cannot be modified once the object has been defined.

```
struct test t;

// from now on, t.i cannot be modified
t.i = 42;  // invalid
```